# Plot a 3 line graphs on a scatter plot_Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I want to plot a 3 line plots on the scatter plot to check how much scatter are the points from the line plot
My scatter plot is obtained as below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([38420690,53439687,82878917,97448841])
y = np.array([47581627,12731149,3388697,911432])

plt.scatter(x,y)

plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Now, I want to plot another 3 line graphs on the scatter plot such that,

1. 1 line graph @ x = y
2. 2nd Line graph @ x = 10*y
3. 3rd Line graph @ x = 10/y

Expected outout

[image]

Please help me how to do this in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a linspace of let's say 50 points using the min and max values of your x array and then apply the operations to it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([38420690,53439687,82878917,97448841])
y = np.array([47581627,12731149,3388697,911432])
min_x = min(x)
max_x = max(x)

newx = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, 50)
newy = newx 
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.scatter(x,y, label='scatter')
plt.plot(newx, newy, color='red', label='x=y') # x=y
plt.plot(newx, newy*10, color='blue', label='x=10*y') # x -> 10*y'
plt.plot(newx, 10/newy, color='black',label='x=10/y') # x -> 10/y

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

This results in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you describe would be the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([38420690,53439687,82878917,97448841])
y = np.array([47581627,12731149,3388697,911432])

val = [0, 97448841*0.5, 97448841]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(val, val, color='red')
plt.plot(val, [i*10 for i in val], color='blue')
plt.plot(val, [i*0.1 for i in val], color='black')
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

But you are likely looking for 3 lines with similar slope but different intersection point so instead (more like in the drawing):

```
plt.plot(val, val, color='red')
plt.plot(val, [i+10000000 for i in val], color='blue')
plt.plot(val, [i-10000000 for i in val], color='black')
```